# excel distribute values across range

Tags: excel, reference, max

i need a formula to distribute values across a range while accounting for the max value possible

*conditions to check:*

1. IF the cell value is less than max then take cell value, ELSE
2. subtract cell value from max AND
3. check conditions if there is a remainder in the subtraction and add to the next row; otherwise place 0

**sample data & ideal outcome** `breakdown` is the ideal outcome

[image]

i know VBA can solve this but i'd rather not if possible. thanks for any help.

Also, not against using a helper column :)

**Updated**

when the values are the same on the series, it replaces with a **0** any idea it can dynamically reset based on the length of the series

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put this in B3 and copy down:

```
=IF(A3<>A2,MIN(A3,$B$1),MIN(A3-SUM(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(A3,A:A,0)):B2),$B$1))
```

[image]

Comment: @emmanueledu I changed the formula to be more dynamic.  The first relied on there always being three, the new formula will allow that to be different.  It can be 1 to as many as wanted.

Comment: the dynamic version makes a big difference. thanks again.

Comment: any idea how i can handle when there is repeating numbers in the series. it replaces with a _0_ when there is no change in the number. I've updated the description with a new image if that helps. thanks again @Scott Craner

Comment: Sure, i'll create a new post.

Comment: before you do,  the question they will ask, is how is excel supposed to know where the break is?  Is it always three? explain the how we are to know when it changes.  @emmanueledu

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161331/discussion-between-emmanueledu-and-scott-craner).